# This might be a very stupid question but is there some inner product like function associated with matrix multiplied by a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the standard inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$

$$\langle w, v \rangle : = \sum_{i = 1}^n w_i v_i$$
which coincides with $w^Tv$.

So my question is, can $A^Tv$ also be defined as some sort of extended inner product function?

i.e., extend $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle: \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$

This question was inspired from someone who asked me if $A^\top v$ was the result of some sort of an inner product and of course I said "no...". But I do wonder if you can extend inner product to cover cases like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ have columns $a_1,\ldots,a_n$.

Then $A^T v$ is the column vector with entries $\langle a_i^Tv\rangle$, $i=1,\ldots,n$.